# What is the Knights' weakspot?

Tags: borderlands-2, borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault

I am playing through the DLC: *Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep*. After a bit of playing, I came across an enemy known as a Knight. I can't seem to be able to find its weak spot. Are there any tactics that are useful when taking them on?

If possible, can you provide a video that shows the process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, Knights (armored guys with shields, can be basic, Shock, Paladin, and Badass) are not vulnerable to headshots. And indeed, their critical location is their butt, as it is their only non-armored area.

Proof or didn't happen:
[image: Take it!]

Flanking them while they crouch behind their shield just become that more fun.

Comment: I figured it was a play on 'bad ass knight'. Using Zero's special that shows the weak spots the butt is indeed highlighted - and 'LOL' is written next to it...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which type of "Knights" you refer to

- [Knights (The Faction)](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Knight_%28faction%29) : They have no typical elemental weakness so you wanna use some slag and some headshots to take them down (like other human ennemies in the game such as Hyperion's soldiers).
- [Knight (A specific ennemy)](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Knight_%28enemy%29) Those are a specific kind of Knights that reflect bullet with their shields. They are considered "Armored" like Loaders thus being sensitive to Corrosive damage. Their weakspot, as human is the head so headhsot it is.

Comment: I have heard that the knights' weak spot is his butt

Comment: @DavidToh I have not had the opportunity to experience this. However I have not encountered any difficulties when fighting Knights. I can't test at the moment but ill try this when i come home.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the knight's weakpoint is just the head, but several of them have helmets that must be shot off before they will be exposed.